# How do I select an element in the DOM using an attribute name that contains a colon?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am using the library Chartist, and it is adding an attribute to some of the elements of the DOM named `ct:value`. For example:

```
<line y1="122.6875" y2="122.6875" x1="242.33333333333334" x2="262.06666666666666" class="ct-bar" ct:value="1"></line>
```

I want to do some selective styling depending on what the value of `ct:value` is.  How would I select that using a CSS selector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). However, as the colon is a reserved character in CSS (for pseudo-classes, etc.), it would need to be escaped. In CSS, this is done with a backslash: `\`.

**Example**

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:sans-serif;}
p{
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:5px;
}
[ct\:value]{
    background:#ccc;
}
[ct\:value="1"]{
    color:red;
}
[ct\:value="2"]{
    color:green;
}
[ct\:value="3"]{
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Zero</p>
<p ct:value="1">One</p>
<p ct:value="2">Two</p>
<p ct:value="3">Three</p>
```